# How to set visibility for an actionbar menu group?

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock

**UPDATE**

Originally I was using ActionBarSherlock I have since created a brand new project using a native android action bar just to test this and I am still getting the same problem.

I am successfully showing/hiding items but not groups. I am rapidly coming to the conclusion that there is a bug in the ActionBar and it is not possible to programmatically set the visibility of a group

**END of UPDATE**

Given the following menu When accessing the Group I get a null pointer exception

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <item android:id="@+id/action_settings"
        android:title="@string/settings"
        android:orderInCategory="100"
        android:showAsAction="never"/>

        <group android:id="@+id/mnu_text_group"
           android:visible="false">
            <item android:id="@+id/mnu_text_type"
                android:enabled="true" 
                android:visible="true"
                android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_text_icon"
            android:showAsAction="always"> 
            </item>
            <item android:id="@+id/text_color"
                android:enabled="true" 
                android:visible="true" 
                android:showAsAction="always" 
                android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_color_line">
            </item>
        </group>        
    <item android:id="@+id/mnu_images"
...
```

In the onPrepareOptionsMenu of the relevant activity I have

```
public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuItem mnuTextGroup = menu.findItem(R.id.mnu_text_group);
    mnuImage.setEnabled(mEnableImageMenu);
    mnuTextGroup.setVisible(false);
    ...
```

The call to `mnuTextGroup.setVisible(false);` raises a null pointer exception

However, by changing the find method to find an item within the group works fine e.g. `MenuItem mnuTextGroup = menu.findItem(R.id.mnu_text_type);`but obviously this works just for the specific item. I know groups are designed for exactly this purpose, to be able to set the visibility of and enable/disable all items within the group but I have been unable to find a way to do this programatically.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Finally found the solution
I needed to use the `setGroupVisible()` method of the menu object passed into the `onPrepareOptionsMenu()` method

This is what worked for me

Instead of

```
MenuItem mnuTextGroup = menu.findItem(R.id.mnu_text_group);
mnuImage.setEnabled(mEnableImageMenu);
mnuTextGroup.setVisible(false);
```

This is what I needed

```
menu.setGroupVisible(R.id.mnu_text_group, false);
```

Answer (score 4):

Simple and one line

```
navigationView.getMenu().setGroupVisible(R.id.groupstaff, false);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use In **Activity** Where You Want to Hide

```
@Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

        getSupportMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main_itemlist, menu);
        boolean isdown = false;

        menu.findItem(R.id.addwork).setVisible(isdown);

        MenuItem mnuTextGroup = menu.findItem(R.id.mnu_text_group);
            mnuTextGroup.setVisible(isdown);

        return true;
    }
```

Comment: Nope, still get null pointer exception. Really don't understand why you would think that using a boolean variable rather than hard coding false would prevent a null pointer exception for mnuTextGroup variable?

Comment: Its Working In my case. I don't understand y you are getting null point exception.

Comment: Perhaps you could share your working application code? I have totally failed to make this work and I would like to see a project where this is working

Comment: For me menu.setGroupVisible() did not work, but this did.

Answer (score 0):

altering the options menu needs to be done within `onPrepareOptionsMenu` or else it sometimes doesn't work (not sure exactly why, hopefully someone else can elaborate):

```
@Override public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
  super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
  // set visibility of menu items here
  return true;
}
```