# Android Fragment to add a menu to Android Activity

Tags: android, android-activity, menu, fragment

I have a fragment for logging into my app, and that fragment is displayed via an activity. If the user logs in successfully, then I need to add a menu to the parent activity. How to do that??

Comment: You mean that you need to add an options menu to the parent activity toolbar or actionBar?

Comment: yes i need to add only if login is successful

Comment: I gonna provide you an answer, I need to know if you know how to send a callback to your activity first.

Comment: i dont have a call back. I just change the fragment from login to homescreen

Answer (score 0):

Menus are inflated during Activity creation. So, in your case, you can only play with it visibility. 
This is not a working code but just that you can get the idea:

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity(), MFragment.Listener {

    ...
    var menu: Menu? = null
    override fun onCreateOptionsMenu(menu: Menu?): Boolean {
        this.menu = menu
        menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.create_order_menu, menu)
        menu?.findItem(R.id.m_item)?.apply {
            isVisible = false
        }
        return true
    }

    override fun onLoginSucceed() {
        menu?.findItem(R.id.m_item)?.apply {
            isVisible = true
        }
    }

}
```

MFragment

```
class MFragment : Fragment() {

    private var listener: Listener? = null

    interface Listener {
        fun onLoginSucceed()
    }

    override fun onAttach(context: Context) {
        super.onAttach(context)
        listener = context as Listener
    }

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
        ...

        listener?.onLoginSucceed()
    }

    companion object {
        @JvmStatic fun newInstance() = MFragment()
    }
}
```

Comment: but then i have different menu for different type of users and that gets solved once user logs in.

Comment: You can use ```groups``` you can show and hide groups programmatically. So you can create a group per user type in your xml and show the correct group after login. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21587341/how-to-set-visibility-for-an-actionbar-menu-group/21742481